# Unity3d lineRenderer is invisible on some parts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I have 3 Spheres and a lineRenderer which is connected to the spheres. I'm using Bezier curves to get a smooth curves between the spheres.

The code is looking like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public Transform p0;
    public Transform p1;
    public Transform p2;

    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.sortingOrder = 1;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        DrawQuadraticBezierCurve(p0.position, p1.position, p2.position);
    }

    void DrawQuadraticBezierCurve(Vector3 point0, Vector3 point1, Vector3 point2)
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 100;
        float t = 0f;
        Vector3 B = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < lineRenderer.positionCount; i++)
        {
            B = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * point0 + 2 * (1 - t) * t * point1 + t * t * point2;
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, B);
            t += (1 / (float)lineRenderer.positionCount);
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is, that the is invisible on some parts when I move the spheres.

[image]

I don't know why this is happening. I'm using Mixed Reality Toolkit. In the best case the line should be displayed as an 3D object like a long cube.

Maybe anybody is familiar with this kind of "error"?

Comment: linerenderer only renders from one size, Like a quad. I would check the points given are correct so that the line is not twisting

Comment: Try a Double-Sided material or set "Cull" to "Off" in your Shader.